# Saving Session data in a log file in Gnome-connection-manager

Tags: putty, gnome, connman

I am using Gnome-connection-manager on my ubuntu system. Earlier i used to have putty for windows where I was able to log all the session data to a text file.
This was done by going to path session->logging and selecting All session output. After which i gave the text file path and all the putty session used to get saved in the text file.

Can anybody let me know what is the equivalent of this in gnome connection manager?

Answer (score 0):

You only have to click the "Settings" icon and fill in the "Logs Path". By default it is `/home/USER`.